# Deleting Apex Classes

Tags: apex

I am struggling with deleting apex classes that my org no longer uses. Why is this an issue? I would like to delete fields that are in the class (so now I cannot delete the field). What is the fastest way for deleting?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way for deleting apex classes and fields by using ANT Tool.

Below is the complete salesforce developer guide explained how to delete classes and fields using ANT tool.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm

Comment: You don't need Ant. `destructiveChanges.xml` deletions work the same with any Metadata API client, including Workbench.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes we can use both Workbench as well as ANT. It depends on which tools you are more familiar.